# Using lookup functions to find sum of numbers that fall within a certain month

Tags: excel

I've been trying to use sum combination of the SUM and the VLOOKUP functions in excel to look through a two column table, 1st column is a range of dates, 2nd is a monetary value, then find all the dates within the month of say June 2019 and then give in one cell the sum of all the values that fall into october.

For example I'd want my code to see this

```
1/06/2019    $600
20/10/2019   $700
6/06/2019    $800
5/10/2019    $900
```

I'd like it to see this and spit out $1400 as it has seen the $600 and the $800 are both from June and added them together.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the sumifs function. So in your exaample (Assume your dates are in column A and $ in column B) it would be =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=1/6/2019",A:A,"<=30/6/2019")

Comment: Thank-you. I was wondering does SUMIFS work across multiple worksheets? or is there something special you have to do to get it there
For instance when I do your code it does exactly what I want but for some reason when I put in
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=Sheet2!B3"....) it spits out zero. I expect it's because of the quotation marks but I'm not sure how one would get around that

Comment: No probs, it can work access multiple sheets, just that when u want to reference a cell with greater than or less than signs it will be ">="&Sheet2!B3

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that ampersands had that function.

Comment: No probs, now you do 